# How do I find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}z^n$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I'm a little unsure about methods on finding the radius of convergence of a function. It would be great to get some help on how to approach these kinds of problems.

Comment: You should accept answers you find correct in the questions you ask. You do that clicking/pressing the "Tick" mark at the left of an answer. It helps other people to read the question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Radius of convergence $R=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$. In your case $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

You can also do (the root test) $\frac{1}{R}= \lim sup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{a_n}$, where $R$ is the radius. Check [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Application_to_power_series).

However, I'm not sure if you can use it. Have you learned it already? I'm assuming the function is a complex one, right? You didn't say that.